# Working with multiple Snowflake tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try to reference multiple Snowflake databases within SQLAlchemy, I receive an error message.  In the below example, I'm trying to create two table objects to join together later.  I'm running SQLAlchemy version 1.4.47.

In this example, I'm trying to create two table objects.  The table object from database one works fine.  However, table two throws an error.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
import sqlalchemy

connection_parameters = {
    "account": 'myaccount',
    "user": 'brian',
    "password": 'xyzzy',
    "role": "myrole",
    "warehouse": 'myware',
    "schema": 'qed',
    'database': 'DATABASE_1'
}

engine = create_engine(URL(**connection_parameters))

connection = engine.connect()
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine)
#This table, in DATABASE_1, works fine.
prim_tbl = sqlalchemy.Table('prim_tbl'.lower(), meta, schema='qed', autoload_with=engine)
connection.execute('USE DATABASE DATABASE_2;').fetchone()
sec_tbl = sqlalchemy.Table('sec_tbl'.lower(), meta, schema='deq', autoload_with=engine)
```

The error is `"Schema 'DATABASE_1.DEQ' does not exist or not authorized."`.  How can I force SQLAlchemy to base sec_tbl on DATABASE_2?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be beneficial to initialize two engines, one with `database: DATABASE_1`, and one with `database: DATABASE_2`, and `autoload_with` points to the corresponding engine

Comment: This doesn't work -- if you try to execute the query, it still tries to retrieve tables from the wrong database.

Comment: Can you show how you are initializing the different databases? It should be two create_engine statements with the database field being different in the json